# External monitor is not detected in Ubuntu 12.04 (detected as Laptop)

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I've been trying to extend my DELL S2340L monitor to my Lenovo y510p laptop. It clones the display fine but does not extend it, it cannot detect it. Nvidia X server settings is also somewhat different (no X Server Display Configuration).
What is the problem and how can I fix it? Thank you.

> lspci | grep VGA
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel
> Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce
> GT 750M] (rev a1)

[image]
[image]

Comment: After I've tried everything, the solution was to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: That's a shame, I have the same issue, and upgrading to 14.04 isn't an option